# Age Analysis Dynamically Sliced with Before Date

Tags: dynamic, powerbi

I am trying to create an Age Analysis for Creditors using a dynamic date slicer.

I followed each individual step specified on [David Churchward's Blog](https://p3adaptive.com/2012/04/aged-debtorsdynamic-banding-in-dax/), but I'm not able to replicate what he suggested there.

Herewith is the result of what I tried:

[image: Current Result]

I'm expecting to see these values each in their own Ageing bucket based on what is outstanding.

Please download my [PBIX](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkbD6y_L8YzvgtxRyYExunFMKx6Agw?e=pkw9Vr) file to see for yourself, then please advise what I did wrong.

The Excel source for PBIX is also in the folder.

Thank you.

Comment: Requirement is not clear. Can you please explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

The blog that you're referring is quite old and DAX has changed a lot since then.

Additionally PowerBI now has a in-built feature called [binning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-grouping-and-binning#using-binning) which can do something similar to what you're looking for.
I was able to generate the below output using that feature which automatically groups the data based on the bin size.
[image: PowerBI Binning Example]

There also a related feature called "[Grouping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-grouping-and-binning#using-grouping)" where you can manually choose the groups and their range. If you're up for it you can use this too. Below is the output for that:
[image: PowerBI Grouping Example]

I uploaded the file with these changes in the [same folder](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkbD6y_L8YzvgtxULkgJhpLNqxD-pg?e=D1sjFn).

---

Another resource that might be helpful for you is [Radacad's article on dynamic banding](https://radacad.com/dynamic-banding-or-grouping-in-power-bi-using-dax-measures-choose-the-count-of-bins)